# JQuery how to choose an option from a select tag by text and make that the default option

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a select tag that looks something like this:

```
<form id="edit">
<select name="school">
<option val="1">School Name1</option>
<option val="2">School Name2</option>
<option val="3">School Name3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

the options are generated from php that are on a sql server, and the javascript is using the same data.

Now then, the jquery I'm using to select it by text is:

```
$('#edit select[name = school] option:contains('+name+')').attr("selected", "selected");
```

I tried some other variations too but none seem to work. So, where am I going wrong exactly? I'm using jquery 1.7.2 at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set selected to true:

```
.attr("selected", true);
```

Instead of:

```
.attr("selected", "selected");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/HueEv/

Comment: Hrmm, it does indeed work on jfiddle. When I was researching this, it seemed to vary how to do this by jquery version.

Comment: Though it seems that the jsfiddle is set to 1.7.2

Comment: This **IS** the jQuery version.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that as soon as I said it. What else could be wrong I wonder?